learning about physical volumes and logical volumes
I have RHEL8 on ESXi in my homelab.  I increased the size of the vmdk by 35 GB.  I rebooted the VM and now see this.
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 135 GiB, 144955146240 bytes, 283115520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1C4D748C-9EC3-45C6-A98F-E140A00A43C7

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1230847   1228800   600M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1230848   3327999   2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  3328000 283115486 279787487 133.4G Linux LVM




Disk /dev/mapper/ol-root: 60.8 GiB, 65305313280 bytes, 127549440 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ol-swap: 7.9 GiB, 8476688384 bytes, 16556032 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ol-home: 29.7 GiB, 31885099008 bytes, 62275584 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
# df -h
Filesystem                            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                              3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                 3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                 3.8G   17M  3.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                                 3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/ol-root                    61G   61G   92K 100% /
/dev/mapper/ol-home                    30G   12G   18G  41% /home
/dev/sda2                            1014M  409M  606M  41% /boot
/dev/sda1                             599M  6.0M  593M   1% /boot/efi
192.168.86.36:/volume1/oracle_backup  3.6T  1.4T  2.2T  39% /DBBackups
192.168.86.34:/nfs/Public/backup      1.8T  973G  835G  54% /DBBackups/wdmycloud
tmpfs                                 766M     0  766M   0% /run/user/1000
[root@oemrepo ~]# pvs
  PV         VG Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sda3  ol lvm2 a--  98.41g    0
# lvs
  LV   VG Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  home ol -wi-ao---- <29.70g
  root ol -wi-ao----  60.82g
  swap ol -wi-ao----   7.89g

I am kind of stuck on how to get the root to expand over the other 35GB I increased the size of the vmdk by.

Grow your partition and grow the pv or create a new partition with the additional space, use that as a new physical volume and add to the existing volume group. Once the size of your volume group has been increased you can assign that space to one or more of your existing lvm’s and then as a final step: grow the file system on that LVM to actually make it available to your system. All of which is fairly well documented by Red Hat and many others

man lvextend ...  or, since you're a RedHat customer ... they have excellent documentation on their portal.

The physical disk now has 135GB (or exactly 133.4GB) but the physical volume or pv still has 98GB because the added space isn't a part of it.
First, install growpart if you haven't already.
yum install cloud-utils-growpart -y

Next, extend the size of the partition to the newly added space:
growpart -v /dev/sda 3

Afterwards, use the command pvresize /dev/sda3 to add the extra space to it.
You can then run pvs and vgs to see the extra space added to the physical volume and effectively, the volume group.
You can then use lvextend to increase the size of /dev/mapper/ol-root to the available space and then xfs_growfs for an xfs filesysem or resize2fs for ext4 or variants.
